# How do I properly pass my functions thru as user-input arguments?

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to pass 3 different functions as the user-arg when i run the program. I've gotten missing function errors multiple times or the code simply doesnt work as intended.

I've tried moving my functions around outside of the "main" function and few function calls. But I think they're wrong since it isn't working.

```
#calculate the root of user-def func "f" on closed
#interval [A,B] using bisection method.

bisec <- function(f,A,B,t){

  abs.dist = abs(B-A)
  rel.dist = (2*abs(B-A))/(abs(A)+abs(B))

  f= f1(x)
  f= f2(x)
  f= f3(x)

  #{stuff happens here}  

  C = (A+B)/2

  while ((abs.dist > t) && (rel.dist > t)){

    if (f(C) < 0 && f(A) < 0){
      A = C
    }
  #{stuff happens here}
  }
  C = (A+B)/2
  return(C)
}

  f1 <- function (x){
    y = cos(x)-0.80+0.10^2
    return (y)
  }
  f2 <- function (x){
    y = -sin(x) + (x/50)
    return (y)
  }
  f3 <- function (x){
    y = (x-3)^5
    return (y)
  }
```

when ran should get something like these:

```
> bisec(f1,0,pi,0.001)
[1] 0.7267234

> bisec(f3,0,5,0.0001)
[1] 2.999954
```

Comment: You have the line `f= f1(x)`. Where is this `x` value supposed to come from? What are you trying to do with those three lines were you are just reassigning `f` each time?

Comment: I'm still relatively new to r language and was trying to call one my functions. @MrFlick

Comment: Stated missing function error in description. @Parfait

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using the `do.call()` function, which is used to run a function stored in a variable/parameter.

The following example illustrates this:

```
f1 <- function (x){
  y = cos(x)-0.80+0.10^2
  return (y)
}
f2 <- function (x){
  y = -sin(x) + (x/50)
  return (y)
}
f3 <- function (x){
  y = (x-3)^5
  return (y)
}

test_call_function_passed_as_parameter <- function(f, x) {
  cat("The value of ", deparse(substitute(f)), "(", x, ") is: ",
      do.call(f, list(x)), "\n", sep="")  # Note the use of list() to pass the arguments to f()
}

test_call_function_passed_as_parameter(f1, 3)
test_call_function_passed_as_parameter(f1, 5)
test_call_function_passed_as_parameter(f2, 3)
test_call_function_passed_as_parameter(f3, 3)
```

which yields the following output:

```
The value of f1(3) is: -1.779992
The value of f1(5) is: -0.5063378
The value of f2(3) is: -0.08112001
The value of f3(3) is: 0
```

Comment: Thank You! However I would like to ask if there is a simpler implementation of this as I'm an "r-novice"? @mastropi

Comment: @TrevonCarter Not that I know of. However, please note that the implementation is quite straightforward (I believe also for an "r novice" :-). Perhaps you got scared by the use of `deparse(substitute())` in my code? I used this only to show a description in the console of what is being computed.  
In fact, in your code you just need to replace e.g. `f(A)` with `do.call(f, list(A))`. Do you still find this complicated? That should be as simple as it can get...

Comment: @TrevonCarter I am glad to hear that. If you consider you are satisfied with the answer, please consider upvoting and/or setting my answer as accepted. Thanks.